# Интерфейс Comparator. Ошибка "cannot infer type arguments"

Tags: java

Столкнулся с ошибкой "cannot infer type arguments" в строке

(SortedSet set = new TreeSet<>(comparatorPerson1); )

Где искать источник ошибки?

```
public class ComparatorPerson1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ComparatorPerson1 comparatorPerson1 =new ComparatorPerson1();
    SortedSet<Person> set = new TreeSet<>(comparatorPerson1);

    set.add(new Person("Ivan","Vroslov",15));
    set.add(new Person("Маша", "Петрова", 23));
    set.add(new Person("Даша", "Сидорова", 34));

    set.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

}

```
public class ComparatorDemo implements Comparator<Person> {

@Override
public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
    return o1.getLastname().compareTo(o2.getLastname());
}
```

}

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private int age;

public Person(String firstname, String lastname, int age) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.age = age;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Person anotherPerson) {
    int anotherPersonAge = anotherPerson.getAge();
    return this.age - anotherPersonAge;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person{" +
            "firstname='" + firstname + '\'' +
            ", lastname='" + lastname + '\'' +
            ", age=" + age + '\''+
            '}';
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Person person = (Person) o;
    return age == person.age && Objects.equals(firstname, person.firstname) && Objects.equals(lastname, person.lastname);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(firstname, lastname, age);
}
```

}

Comment: У вас опечатка, классом-компаратором в вашем коде является не `ComparatorPerson1`, а `ComparatorDemo`; также нет необходимости "запоминать" экземпляр компаратора, достаточно было написать: `SortedSet<Person> set = new TreeSet<>(new ComparatorDemo());`

Answer (score 0):

Вместо создания отдельного класса лучше пользоваться фабричными методами класса [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html): [`Comparator::comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-), [`Comparator::comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-), и т.д.:

```java
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;

// ...

SortedSet<Person> setByLastName = new TreeSet<>(comparing(Person::getLastname));

SortedSet<Person> setByFullName = new TreeSet<>(comparing(Person::getLastname).thenComparing(Person::getFirstname));
```